# How to implement polymorphism in sproutcore?

Tags: model-view-controller, polymorphism, sproutcore

I am developing an application that involves a type hierarchy and started by defining the models for each type via inheritance. When it comes to writing the corresponding controllers I am not sure how to approach the whole thing in a clean way. Should I write only one controller for the base type that is able to handle derived models or should there be one controller for each subtype? How should the view-controller bindings be set up to work with the different controllers?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out SproutCore's new experimental polymorphism support: http://groups.google.com/group/sproutcore-dev/browse_thread/thread/b63483ab66333d15

Answer (score 0):

Here's some information on defining sub-classes and overriding properties and methods:
 http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12412971/Runtime-Objects.

From my (limited) use of Sproutcore, I've only been able to bind 1 view to 1 controller.

As such, if you are planning to use a single view (e.g. ListView) to display your data, then I think you will only be able to bind that view to 1 controller.  This means the 1 base type that is able to handle derived models seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'll try it that way. Still wondering if its possible to do it differently. By the way I am going through your list reordering tutorial. It seems to be quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you populate the content of ArrayController instances with the results of App.store.find calls. SC.Store#find can take an SC.Query instance, which typically looks like:

```
MyApp.myController.set('content') = MyApp.store.find(SC.Query.local(MyApp.MyModel));
```

This should return all instances of MyApp.MyModel, including any instances of MyApp.MyModel's subclasses.

The first argument to SC.Query.local can either be an SC.Record subclass or a string referring to the subclass. So if you've got some intermediary SC.Record subclasses, you might want to try using them there.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers should just be proxies for objects, when dealing with single instances of your model.  In other words, ObjectController can proxy anything.  Here is what I mean in code:

You have two objects, Person and Student.

```
App.Person = SC.Object.extend({
   // person stuff here
})

App.Student = App.Person.extend({
   // student stuff here, you have have all Person things because you are extending person.
})
```

You then want to define controllers:

```
App.personController = SC.ObjectController.create({
   contentBinding: 'App.path.to.person'
})

App.studentController = SC.ObjectController.create({
   contentBinding: 'App.path.to.student'
})
```

note that you would only bind the controller's content to something if the person/student is a result of a selection, or some other flow where bindings fire.  In other words, if you set the person manually (say from a statechart, as the result of an interaction), you would still define the controller but would do

```
App.personController.set('content', person);
```

You set up the controller differently depending on whether the Person is a 'top level' object in your app, or some intermediate object that gets selected.  Also, you might only need one controller, you would only have a studentController and a personController if you were acting on a person and a student at the same time.  Both are just ObjectControllers, and those can proxy anything.

Finally, in your view you would bind the relevant view element to the controller:

...

```
   nameView: SC.LabelView.design({
      layout: {/* props */},
      valueBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('App.personController.name')
   })
```

...

note that the oneway binding is if the name is not going to be changed on the view, if the view can change the name, then just do a normal binding.  Also note the path here.  I am not binding to

```
'App.personController.content.name'
```

Since the personController proxies the object, you bind to the

```
'namespace.controller.property-on-object-controller-proxies'
```

If you are putting a lot of business logic in your controller, you are doing it wrong.  Controllers should just be for proxying objects (at least ObjectControllers should be).  Business logic should be on the models themselves, and decision making logic should be in statecharts.